# Save file to multiple paths

Tags: vba, excel

I've been trying to save a file to two different paths but cant get my head around what's wrong with this code. Googled and read most there is, tried both `SaveCopyAs` and whats in the code.

The first of the two paths gets saved but I get error after the first one.

`Run-time error 1004:`

`Method "save as" of Object'_Workbook' failed`

```
Sub SaveAsTwoPaths()

Dim comps As VBIDE.VBComponents
Dim comp As VBIDE.VBComponent
Dim relPath As String
Dim relPath2 As String

relPath = thisWorkbook.Path & "\Topp 100\" & Range("C1") & ".xlsb"
relPath2 = "\\common\intranet\topp 100" & "\Topp 100\" & Range("C1") & ".xlsb"
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Set comps = ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents
For Each comp In comps
    Select Case comp.Type
        Case vbext_ct_StdModule, _
             vbext_ct_MSForm, _
             vbext_ct_ClassModule
                comps.Remove comp
        Case Else ' Worksheet, Workbook, etc.
            comp.CodeModule.DeleteLines 1, _
                comp.CodeModule.CountOfLines
    End Select
Next comp

' Save a new copy.
ActiveWorkbook.Protect Password:="xxxx", Windows:=False

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=relPath '~< gets saved
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=relPath2
End Sub
```

Comment: `relPath2` is not defined.  You use `relpath` twice????

Comment: @Nathan_Sav forgot the 2 there. its in the original macro. see edit

Comment: is this correct path **\topp 100" & "\Topp 100\** ?

Comment: @MaddyNikam OMG. How did i not see that. i have THE typo of the year. there is a `Topp 100`to many. thx